# Getting problems in my knapsack implementation(PARTY)

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I was trying to do [this simple question](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PARTY/) from spoj today, and it being the knapsack problem, I have implemented it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    while(true)
    {
        int budget, t;
        scanf("%d%d", &budget, &t);
        if(budget == 0 && t == 0)
            break;

        int cost[t], fun[t]; 
        vector<pair<double, int> > knap;
        for(int i = 0;i < t;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d%d", &cost[i], &fun[i]);
            knap.push_back(pair<double, int>(double(fun[i])/double(cost[i]), i));        
        }
        sort(knap.rbegin(), knap.rend());
        int totfun = 0, bud = budget;
        for(int i = 0;i < int(knap.size());i++)
        {
            if(bud - cost[knap[i].second] >= 0)
            {
                bud -= cost[knap[i].second];
                totfun += fun[knap[i].second];        
            }
        }
        printf("%d %d\n", budget-bud, totfun);
    }
}
```

But this solution give WA(Wrong answer). I have tried all the test cases in spoj's own forum, and my code seems to pass them all, Can anyone guide me, this is one of the first DP problems I've tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question does *not* implement exact solution via [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), but a greedy algorithm which in general does not calculate an optimal solution. The task from the link in the question apparently requires generation of an optimal solution, however.

The suboptimality of the greedy algorithm can be proved by considering the following instance.

```
Item 1: Function 6, Cost 4 (Ratio 18/12)
Item 2: Function 4, Cost 3 (Ratio 16/12)
Item 3: Function 3, Cost 3 (Ratio 12/12)

Capacity: 6
```

The greedy algorithm would choose `Item 1`, yielding a profit of `6`. However choosing `Item2` and `Item3` yields a total profit of `7`.

Comment: Hmmm, really ? I don't get it. why do you think so ? I mean, I'm calculating the ratio b/w fun and cost, and then sorting it in descending order and finds the solution.I read this method of solving 0/1 integer knapsack problem via this method...

Comment: @Nib Where did you read about it? It does not always give an optimal solution. This answer is correct.